# calculus of variations 3

Tags: calculus

$$S(x):=\int_{t_i}^{t_f} dt\,L(x(t),\dot{x}(t);t)$$
prove
$$\frac{\partial S(x;t_i,t_f)}{\partial t_f}=\left(1-\dot{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{x}}\right)L(x(t),\dot{x}(t);t)|_{t=t_f}$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This site won't do your homework for you

Comment: Something is definitely wrong. As written, by the FTC the required derivative is $L(x(t_f),\dot x(t_f);t_f)$.